# Counter in js with errors

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create an easier counter. At first, only adding a number worked for me, but reset did not work, so then I decided to look at the tutorial on YouTube and combined my code with it, but errors came out.

codepen - https://codepen.io/Agasfer/pen/vYayEwv

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>CoderslangJS click counter</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>CLICKS:</h3>
<p id="clicks">0</p>
<button type="button" id="incrementCounterButton" onClick="clickHandler(plus)">Click me</button>
<button type="button" id="resetCounterButton" onClick="clickHandler(reset)">Reset</button>

<script>

    let button = document.getElementById('incrementCounterButton');
    button.onClick = clickHandler;
    let par = document.getElementById('clicks');
    let count = 0;
    let res = document.getElementById('resetCounterButton');

function clickHandler(button){ 
    if(button == plus){
    ++count;
    par.innerHTML = count;
}; 
    

    if(button == reset){
        count = 0;
    };
};
```

I decided to look at the tutorial on YouTube and combined my code with it, but errors come out.

Comment: Start by adding the error in your question.

Comment: I'm so sorry, currently I'm studying English in parallel :)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>

  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
      <h1>My other page</h1>

      <h3>CLICKS:</h3>
      <p id="clicks">0</p>
      <button
        type="button"
        id="incrementCounterButton"
        onClick="clickHandler('plus')"
      >
        Click me
      </button>
      <button
        type="button"
        id="resetCounterButton"
        onClick="clickHandler('reset')"
      >
        Reset
      </button>
    </main>
    <script>
  let button = document.getElementById('incrementCounterButton');
      button.onClick = clickHandler;
      let par = document.getElementById('clicks');
      let count = 0;
      let res = document.getElementById('resetCounterButton');

      function clickHandler(button) {
        if (button == 'plus') {
          ++count;
          par.innerHTML = count;
        }

        if (button == 'reset') {
          count = 0;
          par.innerHTML = count;
        }
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

"clickHandler(**plus**)" - here **plus** is a parameter that should be defined a type. If it is string then needs to put inside double or single quote like 'plus'.

```js
  clickHandler(button) {
     if (button == 'plus') { }
   }
```

Here button parameter receiving value as a string so that should be match with string.

Comment: Omg, How did I not notice this :D

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass `1` or `0` to `clickHandler` function when `onClick` event trigger then check if you get value 1 to the increase counter, otherwise set it 0.

Blow code help you to better understand.

```js
let count = 0;

function clickHandler(button){ 
    
    let par = document.getElementById('clicks');
    if(button == 1){
        count += 1;
    } else {                
        count = 0;
    }           
    par.innerHTML = count;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

    <h3>CLICKS:</h3>
    <p id="clicks">0</p>
    <button type="button" id="incrementCounterButton" onClick="clickHandler(1)">Click me</button>
    <button type="button" id="resetCounterButton" onClick="clickHandler(0)">Reset</button>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Martin, there was n need for certain lines of code. I removed those;